# tried killing Node.js for javascript Nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting -

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I was working with the code yesterday and everything was working fine. Today I opened vscode to continue building it up but now I encountered this error. I tried by killing the task Node.js for Javascript and restarted it but still, it didn't work. [image]

Comment: show your package.json's script for running nodemon

Comment: Please add the text you see on the terminal, maybe there is an error somewhere above in the terminal that we don't see.

Comment: please share your package.json file.

Comment: {
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.8",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}